# Insert into DB using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net

I have a FormView that has it's default mode set to "insert".  There are a bunch of controls on the form that the user enters data.  Once I press the insert button, I get this error: Procedure or function sp_fc_vm_insertDebtorContact has too many arguments specified

I am pretty sure the stored procedure is correct so I am wondering if it is my code.  Here is the SqlDataSource code:

> ```
>     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
>         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AuditDevConnectionString2 %>"            
>
>         InsertCommand="sp_fc_vm_insertDebtorContact" 
>         InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
>         SelectCommand="sp_fc_vm_insertDebtorContact" 
>         SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
>         <InsertParameters>
>             <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="DebtorKey" 
>             QueryStringField="DebtorKey" Type="Int32" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Title" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Authority" DefaultValue="0" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Extension" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Email" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Attention" DefaultValue="0" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Ownership" DefaultValue="0" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Guarantor" DefaultValue="0" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Notices" DefaultValue="0" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Addr1" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Addr2" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="City" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="State" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="CellPhone" />
>             <asp:Parameter Name="Country" />
>         </InsertParameters>
>     </asp:SqlDataSource>
> ```

Here is the stored procedure -

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_fc_vm_insertDebtorContact] (@DebtorKey int,  @LastName varchar(50), 
      @FirstName varchar(20), @Title nvarchar(30), @Authority bit, @Extension nvarchar(10), @Email nvarchar(50),
      @Comments ntext, @Phone nvarchar(20), @Attention bit, @Fax nvarchar(20), @Ownership money, @Guarantor bit,
      @Notices bit, @Addr1 nvarchar(30), @Addr2 nvarchar(30), @City nvarchar(30), @State nvarchar(30),  
      @ZipCode nvarchar(10), @CellPhone varchar(20), @Country nvarchar(30))

AS

INSERT INTO [FSDev].dbo.Contacts (ClientKey, DebtorKey, lastname, NameKey, firstname, title, authority, extention,
Email, Notes, Phone, attention, Fax, brokerskey, inactive, [ownership], guarantor, notices, addr1, addr2,
city, [state], zipcode, cellphone, country)

VALUES (0, @DebtorKey, @LastName, LEFT(UPPER(@FirstName)+UPPER(@LastName),20), @FirstName, @Title, @Authority,
@Extension, @Email, @Comments, @Phone, @Attention, @Fax, 0, 0, @Ownership, @Guarantor, 0, @Addr1, @Addr2,
@City, @State, @ZipCode, @CellPhone, @country)
```

The stored procedure works fine in SQL, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can't tell if that's correct based on the markup alone. Can you also post at least the declaration part of the stored procedure (where the arguments are defined)?

Comment: @RickNZ I have posted the stored procedure.  Can you take a look and let me know if you can see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
 private void InsertCommand(Object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{

    SqlParameterCollection _colSqlParameter = new SqlParameterCollection();
    _colSqlParameter.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Last Name Valye";
    _colSqlParameter.Add("LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "First Name Value";
    _colSqlParameter.Add("Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Title Value";
    _colSqlParameter.Add("Extension", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Extension Value";
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(_colSqlParameter);
}

<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SQLFORINSERTDEMO"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString=""
    InsertCommandType = "StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="SP_INSERT"        
    OnInserting="InsertCommand"
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Do I do the same for each parameter?

Comment: yes sure you can do it for all parameter.
even you can get output result from OnInserted command.